# Unable to perform GroupBy on entity type(IQueryable) in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-web-api

The following code is failing:

```
Iqueryable<shift> list = null;

list = context.shifts.Where(o => o.create_date == date).GroupBy(m => m.empId).select(
g=>
new{
empId = g.Key,
time = g.Sum(s => s.hours) // need to calculate sum of hours worked in each employee
}
);
```

It causes the following error to be reported:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Data.Entity.shift'
```

Comment: Use `var` instead of `IQueryable<shift>`. Your expression returns an `IEnumerable` for instances of an anonymous-type, not `shift` values. References to anonymous types must be declared as `var`.

Comment: First off this code has casing problems that would cause it to fail to compile.  Please post the exact code.  Second you're selecting into an anonymous type, but then setting it to a `IQueryable<shift>` which would fail, but with a different error, so again post the actual code.

Comment: The error message you have posted is *not* correct. You should, at the very least, ensure you are giving us accurate information. For that reason, I'm voting to close this question.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to produce some group values based on the shifts table.

The issue you're having is that the Select method is returning a new anonymous type and you try to assign it to `IQueryable<shift>`

You can use `var` like mentioned in the comments, or you can create a new type and use it instead of the anonymous one, like below

```
public class ShiftGroup
{
    public int EmpId { get; set; }
    public int TotalHours { get; set; }
}


IQueryable<ShiftGroup> result =  context.shifts.Where(o => o.create_date == date).GroupBy(m => m.empId).select(
    g=>
    new ShiftGroup {
        EmpId = g.Key,
        TotalHours = g.Sum(s => s.hours) // need to calculate sum of hours worked in each employee
        }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!! Now it is working perfectly. But, I also need to select other attributes such as name, address exists in the table. Is it possible to perform?

Comment: Yes, you just need to add the properties in the defined class and assign them in the Select method.